# How to allocate a new TLS area with clone system call

Tags: linux, pthreads, system-calls

**Short version of question:** What parameter do I need to pass to the `clone` system call on x86_64 Linux system if I want to allocate a new TLS area for the thread that I am creating.

**Long version**:

I am working on a research project and for something I am experimenting with I want to create threads using the `clone` system call instead of using `pthread_create`.  However, I also want to be able to use thread local storage.  I don't plan on creating many threads right now, so it would be fine for me to create a new TLS area for each thread that I create with the clone system call.

I was looking at the man page for `clone` and it has the following information about the flag for the TLS parameter:

```
CLONE_SETTLS (since Linux 2.5.32)
   The newtls argument is the new TLS (Thread Local Storage) descriptor.
   (See set_thread_area(2).)
```

So I looked at the man page for `set_thread_area` and noticed the following which looked promising:

```
 When  set_thread_area()  is  passed  an  entry_number  of -1, it uses a 
 free TLS entry. If set_thread_area() finds a free TLS entry, the value of
 u_info->entry_number is set upon return to show which entry was changed.
```

However, after experimenting with this some it appears that `set_thread_area` is not implemented in my system (Ubunut 10.04 on an x86_64 platform).  When I run the following code I get an error that says: `set_thread_area() failed: Function not implemented`

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h> 
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <linux/unistd.h>

 #include <asm/ldt.h>

int main()
{
  struct user_desc u_info;
  u_info.entry_number = -1; 
  int rc = syscall(SYS_set_thread_area,&u_info);
  if(rc < 0) {
    perror("set_thread_area() failed");
    exit(-1);
  }

  printf("entry_number is %d",u_info.entry_number);
}
```

I also saw that when I use strace the see what happens when `pthread_create` is called that I don't see any calls to `set_thread_area`.  I have also been looking at the nptl pthread source code to try to understand what they do when creating threads.  But I don't completely understand it yet and I think it is more complex than what I'm trying to do since I don't need something that is as robust at the pthread implementation.  I'm assuming that the `set_thread_area` system call is for x86 and that there is a different mechanism used for `x86_64`.  But for the moment I have not been able to figure out what it is so I'm hoping this question will help me get some ideas about what I need to look at.

Answer (score 6):

> I am working on a research project and for something I am experimenting with I want to create threads using the clone system call instead of using pthread_create

In the *exceedingly* unlikely scenario where your new thread *never* calls any libc functions (either directly, or by calling something else which calls libc; this also includes dynamic symbol resolution via PLT), then you can pass whatever TLS storage you desire as the the new_tls parameter to `clone`.

You should ignore all references to `set_thread_area` -- they only apply to 32-bit/ix86 case.

If you *are* planning to use libc in your newly-created thread, you should *abandon* your approach: `libc` *expects* TLS to be set up a certain way, and there is *no way* for you to arrange for such setup when you call `clone` directly. Your new thread will *intermittently* crash when `libc` discovers that you didn't set up TLS properly. Debugging such crashes is exceedingly difficult, and the only reliable solution is ... to use `pthread_create`.

Comment: thanks for the information, yes I do plan to make calls to libc.  Out of curiosity what sort of things does libc use the TLS area for?  Also since it's possible to have programs that don't use pthread_create (single threaded) what happens in this case in regards to setting up the TLS area that libc needs to use.

Comment: Some things libc uses it for: function pointer for making accelerated syscalls (x86), stack canary (if using stack protector), pid cache (used by getpid), tid cache (for identifying owner of locks), errno (which is thread-local). I'm sure there are more uses I'm not thinking of, too.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer is absolutely correct in that setting up a thread outside of libc's control is guaranteed to cause trouble at a certain point. You can do it, but you can no longer rely on libc's services, definitely not on any of the `pthread_*` functions or thread-local variables (defined as such using `__thread` or `thread_local`).

That being said, you can set one of the segment registers used for TLS (GS and FS) even on x86-64. The system call to look for is `prctl(ARCH_SET_GS, ...)`.

You can see an example comparing setting up TLS registers on i386 and x86-64 in [this piece of code](https://github.com/darlinghq/darling-xnu/blob/60dc3751f3a7825b709c3a3359af27805b24c141/darling/src/libsystem_kernel/emulation/linux/machdep/tls.c).